# Less loop variables always sets to the last values

Tags: loops, less

I have .less file:

```
@flag1: fr;
@flag2: en;
@flag3: ru;

@iterations: 3;

.loopingClass (@index, @difference: 0) when (@index < @iterations) {
    @idx: (@index + 1);
    @diff: (@difference - 32);

    (~".my-class-@{index}") {
        my-idx: @idx;
        my-diff: @diff;
        my-index: @index;
        my-difference: @difference;
    }

    .loopingClass(@idx, @diff);
}

.loopingClass (@iterations) {}
.loopingClass (0);
```

How come it generates me .css where `@idx` and `@diff` is always the last values of loop?

```
.my-class-0 {
  my-idx: 3;
  my-diff: -96;
  my-index: 0;
  my-difference: 0;
}
.my-class-1 {
  my-idx: 3;
  my-diff: -96;
  my-index: 1;
  my-difference: -32;
}
.my-class-2 {
  my-idx: 3;
  my-diff: -96;
  my-index: 2;
  my-difference: -64;
}
```

I'm not very good with less, but I did my best and tried many ways to get this loop working. I need `@idx` and `@diff` to be 1, 2, 3 and -32, -64, -96.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying some insane ways to make it work and realized, that maybe less is parsing everything after the loop is finished (or smth. like that). So I thought, maybe I should try to set `@idx` and `@diff` outside of loop. Now my code looks like that and it works as expected:

```
.classOutput(@index, @difference){
    @idx: (@index + 1);
    @diff: (@difference - 32);

    (~".my-class-@{index}") {
        my-idx: @idx;
        my-diff: @diff;
        my-index: @index;
        my-difference: @difference;
    }
}
.loopingClass (@index, @difference: 0) when (@index < @iterations) {
    .classOutput(@index, @difference);
    .loopingClass((@index + 1), (@difference - 32));
}
```

---

So, with the new version of LESS `(~".my-class-@{index}")` throws an error. These changes should help, though didn't test it: `.my-class-@{index}`